# Как становятся классиком?

Tags: общие-вопросы

А мне подумалось: кто, как и когда решает, что этот писатель является классиком, а этот нет? По какому принципу "назначают" классиками?

Answer (score 3):

Какая у Бальзака была биография? Почти никакой. Одна поездка в Россию, насколько мне помнится. А писатель был - гений! Такой лёгкостью слога из наших обладал разве только сам Пушкин Значит, дело не только в биографии. Классик перевернёт душу читателя, заставит помнить себя всю жизнь. Он дарит читателю такие собственные наблюдения, которые сам читатель никогда в себе не нашёл бы самостоятельно. Классик - это учитель на всю жизнь... Что касается Ломоносова, Державина и Пушкина. Насколько Державин пошёл дальше Ломоносова, настолько Пушкин был весомее Державина. "Пророк", "Медный всадник", "Сказка о рыбаке и рыбке", "Евгений Онегин", наконец, - что можно противопоставить из Державина этому краткому списку? Даже "Памятник", заимствованный Пушкиным у Державина, - насколько он значительнее в устах Пушкина! Я знаю: некоторые считают Ф. И. Тютчева выше Пушкина. Но нет! Они не сравнимы ни в каком плане! Лёгкости слога Пушкина как будто нарочно противостоит серый, гранитный стих Тютчева. А как по-разному они пишут о любви! Причём, кажется, у Пушкина такой сильной любви, как у Тютчева, пожалуй, не было в жизни. И тем более, испытав такое чувство, как любовь к Денисовой, Тютчев не смог написать ничего такого, что было бы сравнимо с простыми строчками: "Я вас любил. Любовь ещё, быть может..."... Классиками рождаются, а потом, если удаётся, становятся ими.

Comment: Вам плохо помнится, роман с замужней русской уже интересен, даже фильм сняли довольно интересный именно про его отношения с Ганской. Да и Талант наряду с новаторством у Бальзака был огромен.  
Пушкин поэт безусловно талантливый, но гений его, по-моему, сильно преувеличен. Мне очень нравится его проза, особенно "повести Белкина", но великое большинство его стихов и поэм - это лишь бесчувственная и бессмысленная поделка. Да поделка эта очень качественная, не лишённая элегантности, но за редким исключением его стих - это лишь сувенир, а не памятник. А вот биография вполне себе была впечатляющая.

Comment: Фильм про Бальзака с Ганской я смотрел,но уже плохо помню.  О Пушкине. Я уверен, что у меня сторонников гораздо больше, чем у Вас. Вы знаете, меня всегда удивляло то обстоятельство, что если мне нравится какая-то мелодия, то мне казалось, что она должна нравиться всем вокруг. И вдруг я узнаю, что это не так!! Помню, товарищ мне говорил в ответ на моё высказывание о том, что мне не нравится мелодия песни "Подмосковные вечера": "Как она может тебе не нравиться, если её поёт весь мир?!" Не знаю. Мне она не нравится. А Пушкин мне нравится!! И мне удивительно, что Вам - нет. Что делать?!

Comment: Пару лет назад взяла томик Пушкина, чтобы почитать сыну, долго искала и мало что нашла. Конечно, он еще был маловат. Но дело даже не в нем. Того очарования, которое чувствовала в юности, нет уже... Приходится буквально "выискивать" стихи, которые действительно хочется читать. Многие производят впечатление скорее "альбомных".  

Но хорошие его стихи хороши бесконечно!

Comment: Все-таки поэты-писатели пишут для себя и современников, а там как получится. Если сразу начинать творить для потомков (а какие они будут, непонятно даже гению), то трудновато придется, голодухи не избежать и признания не дождаться.

Comment: @DocentI! Что искать? Ребёнку надо не "Медный всадник" читать, а Сказки - их у Пушкина много. А для себя...? Когда Вы были влюблены(вспомните это время!), почти любой стих Пушкина был завораживающим. "Подъезжая под Ижоры Я взглянул на небеса..."

Comment: Конечно, с течением времени острота впечатлений сглаживается. Естественно, что Вам сейчас показалось творчество Пушкина упрощённым, для юношества. Но те, которые хороши, - это же действительно стихи!! Мало найдётся писателей, у кого всё творчество, драгоценно. Я таких примеров не знаю. Ко всему прочему, Вы тоже изменились - и, может быть, в сравнении с Пушкиным, не в лучшую сторону: приобретя новые качества в других областях, Вы что-то потеряли в понимании стихотворчества. Но Пушкин в этом не виноват.Хотя и Вы - тоже. Слава Богу, что Вы нашли хоть кое-что у Пушкина "хорошим бесконечно"!

Answer (score 0):

Яркая биография, помноженная на писательский талант, с прибавлением к этому известных почитателей.

Comment: Ну, далеко не у всех классиков были такие уж яркие биографии.

Comment: Значит был большой талант и известные почитатели. Если интересность биографии равна нулю, то будет этот человек известен в лучшем случае узкому кругу специалистов. В качестве примера могу привести Державина. Его стихи гораздо интересней, чем у Ломоносова и по мне так превосходят большинство Пушкинских, однако в народной памяти не осталось ни одной цитаты из его произведений, и в лучшем случае о нём помнят, что он будучи "стариком" заметил лицеиста Пушкина.

Answer (score 0):

Кто "назначает" классиков?
Людская память, которая измеряется числом проданных книг после того как мода на данного писателя уже прошла. А в последнее время еще и после того как и реклама утихла. Нельзя забывать, что существенную роль играет и политика властей. В СССР американским классиком был Марк Твен, который в США известен как средний писатель. В то же время классический роман 1984 Оруэлла не был классическим в СССР вплоть до перестройки.